# How to convert mesh defined in a right-handed XYZ coordinate system to a left-handed XZY one

Tags: opengl, matrix, mesh, coordinate-systems

I need a way to pass to these coordinate systems, but I'm struggling with the math.

Basically I have a mesh created "for OpenGL", so right-handed XYZ coordinate system, and I would like to load it in a different environment (the Unreal Engine 4) which uses a left-handed XZY coordinate system.

For now, take this mesh as an example, in its original state:
[image]

If a load it leaving all the vertices as they were, I get this:
[image]

If you look carefully you'll see that it's "mirrored", the left legs of the spider are swapped with the right ones. Also, in the image is not very clear but the depth is off, I can see "inside" the spider (if you notice, the eyes are missing because of that).

Now, if I swap the Y coordinate of each vertex with -Y I basically get the same result as the original:
[image]

Now, the mesh format I'm using has objects hierarchies, meaning that a subset of the mesh may have as parent another subset, and if that's so it has a position and a rotation matrix relative to the parent associated to it. This means more problems when loading the mesh, because also the rotation matrix and position are defined in the wrong coordinate system.
To apply this changes I create the vertices, then the object made up of these vertices, assign it its parent and then apply the rotation matrix and the position.

Take for instance this mesh, defined with this format; all the various part the compose it are hierarchical in the way I described:
[image]

If I load it as it is, with the vertices, relative rotation matrices and positions in the wrong coordinate system, I get this:
[image]

Which kind of looks the same, except that it's "mirrored" along an axis. Notice that yellow thing (wouldn't know how to call it) in the rightmost part of the image: it's on the opposite side respect of its position in the original image.
Also, if you look at the text "BROKK" (which is not a texture, it's made up of vertices) it's reversed too.

Now, if I apply the same trick as with the spider, switch the Y to -Y, I get this:
[image]

Now it doesn't look mirrored, but the "arm" of the machine is all wrong, probably because I'm leaving the relative rotation matrices and positions in their orignal coordinate system maybe? I tried messing with them, but I get all kind of weird things going on, nothing close to the solution.

I've looked a lot around, an to switch between coordinate systems I've found contrasting ideas. I tried applying this matrix below to switch the axis and invert the axis going "forward", but the result is crazy wrong:

(1   0   0)
(0   0   1)
(0  -1   0)

I'm helpless, do you have any ideas?

**EDIT:** thanks to Ripi2's suggestion (only inverting the sign to the Z coordinate) I've kind of got closer to the ideal solution. This is the result:
[image]

Even though it's upside down (I can simply rotate it later) it's not mirrored anymore. Still, in that picture I'm only inverting the Z coordinates of the vertices of the mesh and of the childrens positions. In the picture all the parts except the arm are in the right orientation because their rotation matrix is the identity matrix. In the arm though the rotation matrix isn't the identity, and since I'm leaving it as it was in the original coordinate system it looks all wrong.

I need a matrix of some kind to multiply to each rotation matrix, but I've no idea what!

Comment: Have you tried changing only Z sign?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the original post with the results

Answer (score 1):

Matrix transforming from `X+ right, Y+ up, Z- deep` to `Y+ right, Z+ up, X+ deep`

```
 0  1  0  0
 0  0  1  0
-1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  1
```

And its inverse

```
0  0 -1  0
1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0  0  1
```

Without matrix code may look like this:

```
x2 = -z1
y2 = x1
z2 = y1
```

### Edit

You get wrong result? Perhaps you have a different system-change. For example if just changing Y sign is enough this is the matrix:

```
1  0  0  0
0 -1  0  0
0  0  1  0
0  0  0  1
```

Remember matrix calculating order `Result = Transform * Origin`.

If the model is composed by several objects in hierarchy the proccess goes like this:

1. Each model is translated and rotated with its own matrices, or
   with the one that composes ORDERED both transformations. It's
   supposed that if data come from a file, the axis-system is the same
   for all.
2. Once the full world is constructed, then you set the camera by using
   a view matrix and a projection with another matrix. In this point is where you want apply your axis-system transform matrix.

Let's take the arm-end in your model. It has its own matrix T1 (e.g. composed by a rotation and then a translation, T1 = T·R). When it's chained to the rest of the arm (who has its T2 matrix) it must get also the main arm transform. So the result matrix to apply to arm-end is T2·T1 (notice the order, not T1·T2). If the whole arm is chained to other part then the arm-end matrix needed is T3·T2·T1.

Now apply view matrix (V), the axis-change (A), and projection (P). The resultant matrix for the arm-end is P·A·V·T3·T2·T1.

Perhaps it gets difficult to define projection in the new axis-system. If it's just a matter of changing some sign and swapping axis, it's better to apply after projection: A·P·V·T3·T2·T1

Comment: Thanks again Ripi2! This kind of works, now the mesh is shifted by 90° around the Y axis and it faces towards Y+. 
But what about the rotation matrices for the pieces? I tried applying the matrix you gave me to the relative rotation matrices, but it comes up a mess... I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Draw in a paper both axis systems. See the code I show, whose first line means "when I send X I get -Z"  Compare to the matrix form, do some matrix calcs by hand. Use one or the inverse, the one that works. Try do deduce yourself if you have different systems.

Comment: I tried all day to visualize it, but I'm going nowhere at all and I'm getting more and more confused. I tried a bunch of matrices, but maybe I'm doing something wrong at the core. What I'm doing is this:
1) Convert each vertex to the other coordinate system, the same way you said
2) Create the object using those vertices
3) Take the rotation matrix for that object and apply your rotation matrix, like this: newRotationMatrix = oldRotationMatrix * matrixConverter, where matrixConverter is your matrix.
Is this method correct? Because I'm doing this all day with different matrices, but nothing

Comment: No, that's not the right order. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: I don't think I understand. I can't change the view or the projection matrices. The only thing I can do is load the model applying the transformations on it in order for it to look "normal" with the current view/projection settings. With this in mind, when should I apply the axis-system transform?

Comment: The model incorporates all objects matrices, right? Then most is done. Apply the axis change at last: matrixToUse= axisTransMatrix · currentProjViewMatrix.

Comment: Well, that's actually what I was doing, applying "at the end". But actually I managed to get it working, even though it's a little bit different from your solution. Honestly, I still have to understand why it's working! Actually if you could tell me I'd appreciate it. I'll write the solution as an anwser

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've found. I need to apply a matrix to each vertex, and then apply the same matrix to the roto-translation matrix that each hierarchical component has. The matrix is this one:

```
1 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
```

In code (remember, I'm using the Unreal engine), it's something like this:

```
// Iterating over all vertices of the mesh
for(int i = 0; i < verticesNumber; i++)
{
    FVector4 vertex;

    // Getting the coordinates in the original mesh coordinate system.
    // Here the method GetX(), GetY(), GetZ() retrieve the coordinates from the mesh file somehow
    vertex.X = GetX();
    vertex.Y = GetY();
    vertex.Z = GetZ();

    // Creating the matrix that will transform these coordinates in the new coordinate system
    FMatrix mat = FMatrix::Identity;

    mat.M[0][0] = 1, mat.M[0][1] = 0, mat.M[0][2] = 0;
    mat.M[1][0] = 0, mat.M[1][1] = 0, mat.M[1][2] = 1;
    mat.M[2][0] = 0, mat.M[2][1] = 1, mat.M[2][2] = 0;

    // Applying the matrix
    vertex = mat.TransformFVector4(vertex);

    vertices.Add(FVector(vertex.X, vertex.Y, vertex.Z));
}

/* Then I create the indices, normals, and so on. */

// Now I get from the file the roto-translation matrix for the current object and apply the same matrix like this (note that I multiply before and after; this was mainly what I was missing):
rotationTranslationMatrix = mat * rotationTranslationMatrix * mat;

// Then I set the new matrix, relative to the parent of the current object
FVector position;
position.X = rotationTranslationMatrix.M[0][3];
position.Y = rotationTranslationMatrix.M[1][3];
position.Z = rotationTranslationMatrix.M[2][3];
mesh->SetRelativeLocationAndRotation(position, rotationTranslationMatrix.Rotator());
```

Thise code gets executed for each part that compose the mesh. The end result is this, for the model I used as an example:
[image]

Note that it's shifted by 90 degrees along the X axis. I don't know how to avoid this, but for what I need is enough to just rotate the mesh after the creation, like this:

```
FRotator rotation;
rotation.Yaw = 0.0f;
rotation.Pitch = 0.0f;
rotation.Roll = -90.0f;

mMesh->SetWorldRotation(rotation);
```

End result:
[image]

Thanks again for the help Ripi2!

Comment: With the first matrix (`m`) you swap Y,Z for all vertices before they are proccessed. `m·T·m` does two swaps, the first one restores vertex due to swapping already swaped Y,Z. Can you avoid it? Matrix rotation -90 over X axis is very similar to `m`, just the "bottom" 1 becomes -1

Comment: What do you mean by "the first one vertex due to swapping already swaped Y,Z"? Actually, I tried switching the sign of the bottom 1, but it messes A LOT the rotations of everything, not sure it's right

Comment: res = m * v= (0,1,1,0) * (x,y) produces (y,x). You apply 'm' first to each vector and then in m*t*m (the right-most m). I don't know about UE4 axis, so I don't know the right matrix to apply here.

Answer (score 0):

To make a matrix for transformation from opengl to unreal coordinate system you need to:

1. Replace Ygl with Zu;
2. Replace Xgl with Yu;
3. Replace Zgl with -Xu;

FMatrix Mgl2u = FMatrix::Identity;

`Mgl2u.M[0][0] = 0;  Mgl2u.M[0][1] = 1; Mgl2u.M[0][2] = 0;
Mgl2u.M[1][0] = 0;  Mgl2u.M[1][1] = 0; Mgl2u.M[1][2] = 1;
Mgl2u.M[2][0] = -1; Mgl2u.M[2][1] = 0; Mgl2u.M[2][2] = 0;`